# What is the best place to call ajax which is calling an API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api

I know there are many question like this but i didn't found a proper solution for me.

I am calling API using ajax so my problem is my web page gets unresponsive so some where I have found that this is just because of the improper ajax handling can you please help to know where do I put my ajax.I need ajax to be called on the load of the page.

I have tried calling ajax without any function like..

```
show('ajax Call start for player');
$('#loading').show();
$.ajax({
    url: '/home/getPlayers',
    success: function (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        playerData = data.Data;
        show('data of player');
//        show(playerData);

        showPlayers(1);
        show('ajax Call complete for player');
        flag = 1;
    }
});

show('ajax Call start for loadplayeronpitch');

$.ajax({
    url: '/home/checkUserTeam',
    success: function (data) {

        while (true) {
            if (flag) {
                loadUserTeampitch(data);
                break;
            }
        }
        show('ajax Call complete for loadplayeronpitch');
    }
});
```

This is not working which cause the unresponsive page.

then from other questions I have tried calling the ajax in following functions

```
$(document).load(function(){

});
$(function(){

});
$(document).bind("load", function () {

});
```

but this all are also not working properly can you help me for this?

Thank you.

Comment: but sometimes I am getting the result and sometimes tere is a crash so what can be the problem?

Comment: Ajax is asynchronus, so you can't judge the sequence of multiple ajax calls, i think you should add something like this $.ajaxSetup({async:false});

Comment: @Newinjava you should not use `async:false` as a solution.

Comment: @t.niese please give me the reason.

Comment: @Newinjava because then the browser will block while the request is done. If the connection is bad, the server it slow or much data needs to be requested, then it will hurt user experience. There are only rare cases where `async:false` should be used.

Comment: actually I want the ajax call start parallelly and the function in the second ajax call should be call after the first ajax call success.

Comment: @SandhyaGor I updated and undeleted my answer to add the `$.when` I think it should work the way you expect.

Answer (score 4):

This should work like you want to, but I can't test it right now.

```
$('#loading').show();
var deferedA = $.ajax({
    url: '/home/getPlayers',
    success: function (data) {
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        playerData = data.Data;
        show('data of player');
//        show(playerData);

        showPlayers(1);
        show('ajax Call complete for player');
    }
});

show('ajax Call start for loadplayeronpitch');

var deferedB = $.ajax({
    url: '/home/checkUserTeam'
});

//wait until both request are finished
$.when(deferedA, deferedB)
.done( function (dataA, dataB) {
    loadUserTeampitch(dataB);
    show('ajax Call complete for loadplayeronpitch');
});
```

**EDIT** I would suggest to use [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instead `$.when`  (the *Promise like*  implementation of jQuery is a bit strange), but the *problem*  with `Promise` is that it is only available with the newer browser, for older one you need a library like [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) or [when](https://github.com/cujojs/when)

Comment: you could get rid of `flag = 1` just for sake of completeness

Comment: @devnull69 remove it right at the moment you commented ;)

Comment: I will have to study $.when and will see the result thank you.

Comment: @SandhyaGor I would suggest to look also [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and not that much at `$.when`  the _Promise like_  implementation of jQuery is a bit strange. The _problem_  with `Promise` is that it is only available with the newer browser, and with older one you need a library like [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) or [when](https://github.com/cujojs/when)

Answer (score 4):

The unresponsiveness is caused by your `while(true)` loop, so never ever do this again :-)

What you want to do is: Run the second ajax call only after the first one finishes. So you should put both ajax calls into separate functions, then call the first function on page load.

In the success part of the first ajax (inside the first function), call the second function. Done.

```
function firstAjax() {
   $.ajax({
       url: '/home/getPlayers',
       success: function (data) {
           data = JSON.parse(data);
           playerData = data.Data;
           show('data of player');
           //show(playerData);

           showPlayers(1);
           show('ajax Call complete for player');
           secondAjax();
       }
   });
}

function secondAjax() {
   $.ajax({
       url: '/home/checkUserTeam',
       success: function (data) {
          loadUserTeampitch(data);
       }
   });
}

$(function() {
  firstAjax();
});
```

Comment: actually I have puted while over there bcoz they both API gets a huge data so if first gets the data and then second will call it will take a long time

Comment: I have done it bcoz I have seen in the network that all call starts at the same time so I thought it can be done Parallelly.

Comment: It doesn't matter. A `while(true)` in Javascript will never work because the program flow cannot be interrupted for the callback of the first Ajax. Mind that Javascript is single threaded! If you block this thread there is no way out.

Comment: can AJAX call start parrallely? can we give any dependency to the ajax calls?

Comment: It can be done in parallel (from a pure technical point of view). But your logic demands that your second ajax depends on the result of the first one (as far as I understand your code). So there is no parallelism in your logic

Comment: I would suggest to use `Promise.all` or `$.when( d1, d2 )`  for this situation.

Comment: actually call should be made parrallaly but the execution of the function that I am calling in the second ajax call only that should be done after the first ajax call completes the second ajax call is not dependent on the first one only. the function that I am calling in the second ajax call in  that some part needs the result of the first one

Comment: I don't know whether or not `when` will respect the order of `d1` and `d2`, and I also don't think so. It will only resolve the promise after both ajaxes finished ... no matter in what order

Comment: ajax call should be started parallely but the execution of the function under the second call is only dependent on the success of the first. so what can I do in this situation.?

Comment: @SandhyaGor In that case I would second t.niese for using `when`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** : If you want to go simple than you can use below approach..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var flag = 0;
        var data1;

        $('#loading').show();
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() {
                show('ajax Call start for player');
            },
            url: '/home/getPlayers',
            success: function(data) {
                flag++;
                data = JSON.parse(data);
                playerData = data.Data;
                show('data of player');
                showPlayers(1);
                show('ajax Call complete for player');
                checkFlag();
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function() {
                show('ajax Call start for loadplayeronpitch');
            },
            url: '/home/checkUserTeam',
            success: function(data) {
                flag++;
                data1 = data;
                show('ajax Call complete for loadplayeronpitch');
                checkFlag();
            }
        });

        function checkFlag()
        {
            if (parseInt(flag) == parseInt(2))
            {
                loadUserTeampitch(data1);
            }
        }

    });
</script>
```